# Intermittent power supply voltage issue buzzing

Tags: power-supply, power, buzzing

I have a power supply for an eprom programmer that is supposed to output +30vdc +15vdc -15vdc +5vdc and it will start and work sometimes but most of the time now it fails to start or fails within a minute or two with buzzing of a component and the voltages drop or disappear.  When it works there is no buzzing.  It's 20+ years old so I replaced all the capacitors, re-soldered all the pads on the board and visually inspected for cracks and didn't find any. I'm just hoping for advice from someone more experienced in power supply circuitry than I am to point me in the right direction. It has a couple of small transformers, a few coils, a few C2518 bridge rectifiers, and resistors, etc.

Edit: The buzzing seems to be coming from the center of the board.  I've added a picture.

So I guess my question is how do I go about troubleshooting the issue?

Thanks,

Justin.

[image]

Comment: You need to ask a question, please edit in a question you want answered.

Comment: Troubleshooting a commercial device may be deemed off-topic, but it would help if you can show images of the circuit board and describe the nature of the buzzing (is it power line frequency or high pitched whine). A valid question may be what steps would be needed to determine the likely problem.

Comment: I added a picture.  It's like a mechanical low pitch buzzing perhaps close to 60hz, not high pitch or whine.

Comment: Main culprit in power supplies are dried up electrolytic capacitors. Consider what your own time is worth for troubleshooting it and potentially not being able to fix it in the end versus the cost of a new one. Also, some power supplies buzz new from the factory (bad design), so the root cause of it working intermittently may have nothing to do with the buzzing.

Comment: I mentioned in the post that I already replaced all the capacitors.   I was referring the the electrolytic ones.  I didn't replace any other film or ceramic capacitors.  Yes, time is certainly a factor but it's nice to have something in it's original condition and it's hard to find a power supply with those voltages that will fit in the original case.  It just seems the buzzing corresponds to it not working since it works when there is no buzzing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few steps to troubleshoot such problems:

1. Be very careful taking measurements on line powered switching supplies. Use an isolation transformer or a GFCI circuit.
2. Read the input current when operating normally or in failure mode.
3. Try using freeze-spray on components to see if that causes or stops the failure.
4. Scrub the board with alcohol to remove flux, followed by detergent and rinse with clean water, and drying with heat gun or toaster oven on low heat.

Here are a few resources to help understanding multiple output switching supplies, and I suggest you do an internet search on those terms. Also try to identify all components and search on those part numbers. You might find a similar design schematic.

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva559c/snva559c.pdf

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/switch-mode-power-supply.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mtf0cki0llY (This shows mostly multiple output boost multiplier circuits. Useful info, but not applicable to a line operated switching supply)

https://www.eleccircuit.com/the-old-pc-power-supply-circuit/ (This provides schematics of older desktop computer power supplies, which may be more similar to your PSU)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I've tried freeze-spray on the different components without fixing or causing the problem.  I scrubbed the board to remove flux after I re-soldered it and cleaned and dried it thoroughly.  It doesn't seem to be thermal related but it's strange to work sometimes or not even if it's been off for hours.  I'll check out the links you provided.

Comment: The freeze spray can identify intermittent poor connections or failing components. The 50 Hz buzzing likely indicates a problem with input rectifiers and capacitors. You should find 300-350 VDC on the large capacitors.

Comment: I thought the buzzing might be coming from the larger transformer in the middle of the board.  I already replaced all the electrolytic capacitors with new ones.  It seems strange to me that it hasn't 100% failed if it's a rectifier and it doesn't seem to be thermal related.  I'll check for that voltage range when I get a chance.  Thanks again.

Comment: Update:  I measure 165VDC across both of the large capacitors so maybe the problem is upstream of that with the input rectifiers?

Comment: The large capacitors are 200V so maybe that's correct and the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: For 120 VAC the voltage on the capacitors will be about 165 VDC. I may have assumed you had 220 VAC 50 Hz. Buzzing is often caused by loose laminations in a transformer, but a switching supply usually has ferrite cores. You will probably need to use an oscilloscope to track down the problem.

Comment: That makes sense, yes 120vac input.  I have an oscilloscope but since I'm unfamiliar with switching power supplies I don't know what or where to test.  I've tried following the links you posted and it makes some sense but it's still a bit much to understand.  When the power supply is buzzing the -15vdc output is 0v two +5v outputs are +3v, one +5V is 0V the +30v is +19v and the +15v is +10v if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: That would probably indicate that the drive to the main transformer is not working properly. There should be a couple of high voltage power transistors that provide a square wave or PWM to the primary. It might be dangerous to try using your scope on these. There should be multiple secondaries that will connect to diodes, often in full wave center tap configuration. You might be able to safely look at these waveforms, which should change between good operation and failure. But the problem is most likely on the primary side, You might try re-soldering all components.